# How to access self properly inside escaping blocks in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting some crashes in the code below. I think the crash is caused by the block (LoadXZYAPI) escaped and access properties of ViewControllerA that already got dealloced. So when strongSelf.data.* is being access, strongSelf returns nil or in a dealloc memory location and cause the crash.

Is there any way to prevent this crash without checking for strongSelf each time I try to access its attributes (data.*)? What's the best practice in this scenario without making LoadXZYAPI non-escaping?

Thanks in advance

```
class ViewControllerA {

        var data: [String: Any]?

        func loadData(){

            LoadXZYAPI() { [weak self] (data:Any?) in

                if let strongSelf = self {

                    strongSelf.data = data

                    DispatchQueue.global(qos:.default).asyc {

                        // process self.data
                        let imageData = GetImageData(data:strongSelf.data["image_name"])

                        if let data = data, let image = UIImage(data:imageData) {

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                strongSelf.imageView = nil

                                strongSelf.imageView = CustomView(image: image) <-- Crashes randomly after this line
                                strongSelf.imageView!.width = strongSelf.map["width"] as? CGFloat
                                strongSelf.imageView!.height = strongSelf.map["height"] as? CGFloat
                                strongSelf.imageView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(hex: "#efefef")
                                strongSelf.imageViewWrapper.addSubview((strongSelf.imageView)!)
                                strongSelf.imageViewWrapper.bringSubview(toFront: (strongSelf.imageView)!)
                                strongSelf.imageView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                                    (strongSelf.imageView?.leadingAnchor)!.constraint(equalTo: (strongSelf.imageViewWrapper?.leadingAnchor)!),
                                    (strongSelf.imageView?.trailingAnchor)!.constraint(equalTo: (strongSelf.imageViewWrapper?.trailingAnchor)!),
                                    (strongSelf.imageView?.topAnchor)!.constraint(equalTo: (strongSelf.navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor)!),
                                    (strongSelf.imageView?.bottomAnchor)!.constraint(equalTo: (strongSelf.imageViewWrapper?.bottomAnchor)!),
                                    ])

                                self?.didUpdateImageView()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the exact messages you get when it crashes? Edit your question to include them by copy/paste, or add screenshots.

Comment: Also, the code you posted seems fishy, because `data` is of type `Optional<Any>`, any that type doesn’t have members named `a` or `b`. It is easier to help you if you post code that actually triggers the problem, instead of made-up code that has its own problems.

Comment: Anyway, the likeliest problem is that `label1` is an implicitly-unwrapped optional that is nil, either because you didn’t connect it in the storyboard, or because you haven’t loaded your view hierarchy yet.

Comment: Thanks, @robmayoff. I've updated my code snippet. The data prop is not Any? but [String: Any]?. The actual UI code varied between my VCs but they basically just access data and update some UI. I'm a believer now that I shouldn't be using strongSelf here because if the VC is dealloc or dismissed/disappeared before the API get to finish and the block is escapes to exec the remaining codes, strongSelf may be unsafe to use, hence the crash. Plz correct me if i'm wrong. I just want to know what's the best practice in dealing with escaping block + self + UI. Anyway to stop execing if self is nil...

Answer (score 2):

This should be safe:

```
func loadData(){

    LoadXZYAPI() { [weak self] (data:Any?) in

        //didn't bother putting a guard here since you don't need a strong ref here
        self?.data = data

        DispatchQueue.global(qos:.default).asyc {

            guard let strongSelf1 = self else {
                return
            }

            //use strongSelf1

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let strongSelf2 = self else {
                    return
                }

                //use strongSelf2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake. I actually tried that and it's still crashing randomly inside //use strongSelf2.

Comment: have you checked if data is nil?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my code snippet as suggested by Rob. I've checked data before using it in my UI code.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you must capture weak self in each closure if you assume that viewController may be dismissed at some time during load

```
func loadData(){

    LoadXZYAPI() { [weak self] (data:Any?) in

        guard let strongSelf = self else {
            return
        }

        strongSelf.data = data
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async { [weak self] in

                // process and manipulate self.data

                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in

                    // Update UI
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So inside my "Update UI" code, wouldn't I need some force wrapping which would still cause the crash (code below). Unless I add if let for each attribute.

label1.text = (self?.data)!.a

Comment: @tereks You are not correct. Capturing `weak self` is required only in the first closure.

Comment: dispatchQueue closures are @escaping I.e. captures context. That’s why we must use weak self to prevent retaining

Comment: @sonoluminescence no force unwrapping, use guard unwrap instead

Comment: I’d love to see an example where not capturing self in each closure will produce a crash or some unexpected behavior

Comment: @iWheelBuy I thought I was clear about dispatchQueue.async retaining controller ( self ). I see unexpected behavior in viewController life cycle when it not being freed from memory after dismiss or pop.

Comment: Capturing weak controller is required in outer closure. In each inner closure controller is already weak and it is not required to weakify it again.